# Including content into an add_shortcode() function

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode, include

**my_html.php**

```
<?php 

global $wp;
$op = get_option( 'mcc_d' );
$post_title = get_the_title();

isset( $this->op['mcc_d_text'] ) ? $mcc_d_text = $this->op['mcc_d_text'] : $mcc_d_text = '';

$html = '<div id="mcc_d_content">';
    $html .= 'some content';
$html .= '</div>';
```

And this is the **shortcode.php** file:

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {exit;}

include( PLUGIN_PATH . 'parts/my_html.php' );

function mcc_d_shortcode() {
    global $html;
    return $html;
}

add_shortcode( 'mcc_d_content', 'mcc_d_shortcode');
```

What doesn't work here is the shortcode output `($html)`, it's empty even when I make $html global (which what I'm trying to avoid)... what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You should also do `global $html;` or `global $wp, $html;` from the `my_html.php`. But why don't you just move the `include()` to the shortcode function? That way, no need to `global $html;`..

Comment: @SallyCJ I started by adding the include inside the function but that didn't work.. Yes, making $html global on the other file as well worked, thanks a lot : )

Comment: That's weird, because (based on your code) if you `include()` from the shortcode, the `$html` doesn't need to be global - in `mcc_d_shortcode()`, `include( PLUGIN_PATH . 'parts/my_html.php' ); return $html;` should work fine.

Comment: One would assume it yes, but it doesn't for some reason... it has to do with how `add_shortcode()` works I guess ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Well then, at least, use a unique variable name.. "$html" is too generic. :) But still, I hope you'd find a way to make the variable work without making it global.